# Python Script - DNS Resolution

Tags: python

I've written the following python code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

inputfile = open('list2.txt' , 'r')
outputfile = open('results.txt' ,'w')
for lines in inputfile.readlines():
    runproc = subprocess.Popen(["dig", lines],stdout=outputfile,)

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Simply executes dns queries in a list on domains and writes the output to a file.
The list2.txt has the following format :

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
```

The outputfile (results.txt) writes the following export and subsequently fails :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2 <<>> www.domain1.com

;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 12561
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.domain1.com\010.      IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       5       IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net.
```

If you observe carefully the output ,the code adds a weird \010 besides domain and of course the dns resolution fails.
I cant figure out whats going on.
Any ideas ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could it just be the newline character at the end of the line? Tried `subprocess.Popen(["dig", lines.strip()], ..`?

Comment: Thank L3viathan for the reply.The script now outputs :                           
   dig: '' is not a legal name (unexpected end of input)

Comment: Got an empty line somewhere in the `list2.txt`?

Comment: yes,it was an empty line.Problem solved with strip() and removal of empty line. Thanks a lot L3viathan and Stackoverflow!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a ASCII character (below one of ascii table rows)

> \010   8   BS  \x08  ^H \b (Backspace)  (\b matches backspace inside
>   [] only)

I received similar errors while opening the file across multiple text editors, or simply editing the file a lot even in the same text editor. Try creating a new file, format it and if it doesn't help, then create the file like:

```
touch input_file.txt
echo "www.domain1.com" >> input_file.txt
```

otherwise simply create a python file like input_file.py in the same directory and store addresses as static values:

```
addres1 = "www.domain1.com"
```

then import the input_file.py in the main project and use like

```
input_file.address1
```